# Ubuntu doesn't find USB device

Tags: usb, android

I have an Beagle bone black connected via USB after installing some software `ssh` didn't work any more. Somehow the USB device is not recognized any more at all. I did try to connect my Samsung Galaxy S2 which did also not work. It does charge but I can't access any of the contents.

I tried `lsinput` without success. Also `udevadm monitor --udev` didn't detect anything when I connect the USB cable.

Any suggestions?

To clearify: A drive was automaticly added (a ~70 MB drive with some documentations). As far as I understand it is the USB connection also a network connection in this case (or at least should be) and the BBB a router which Broadcast over 192.168.7.3 and is reachable over 192.168.7.2 but the connection can often not be established. Somethimes it works but most of the time not. It only shows me network connection terminated all the time and timeout's on `ping` as well as `ssh`.

Once a `ssh` connection is established it is fine and the connection doesn't die anymore. `ifconfig` doesn't really show something when I have connection problems, when everything works it show's an eth1 connection.

`sudo fdisk -l`:

```
Disk /dev/sda: 250.1 GB, 250059350016 bytes
255 Köpfe, 63 Sektoren/Spur, 30401 Zylinder, zusammen 488397168 Sektoren
Einheiten = Sektoren von 1 × 512 = 512 Bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Festplattenidentifikation: 0x0004b1bb

   Gerät  boot.     Anfang        Ende     Blöcke   Id  System
/dev/sda1   *        2048   484239359   242118656   83  Linux
/dev/sda2       484241406   488396799     2077697    5  Erweiterte
/dev/sda5       484241408   488396799     2077696   82  Linux Swap / Solaris

Platte /dev/sdb: 73 MByte, 73995264 Byte
3 Köpfe, 48 Sektoren/Spur, 1003 Zylinder, zusammen 144522 Sektoren
Einheiten = Sektoren von 1 × 512 = 512 Bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Festplattenidentifikation: 0x00000000

  Gerät  boot.     Anfang        Ende     Blöcke   Id  System
```

`sudo lsusb`:

```
Bus 002 Device 005: ID 1d6b:0104 Linux Foundation Multifunction Composite Gadget
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 0483:2016 SGS Thomson Microelectronics Fingerprint Reader
Bus 005 Device 003: ID 046d:c016 Logitech, Inc. Optical Wheel Mouse
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 005 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 006 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 007 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
```

Comment: Edit your question and post the output of these command while connected to your USB: 1. `sudo fdisk -l` and 2. `sudo lsusb`.

Comment: @SauravKumar done thank you for taking interrest

Comment: I don't know exactly what is the problem.. Hope [this](http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/ubuntu-63/usb-stick-not-detected-876180/) post would help you..

Comment: @SauravKumar, hm not really I added some more content. I can still not connect to the BBB